# AmChart StartDuration doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm having trouble with the `startDuration` property of an `AmChart` serial chart.

My code for setting the chart at the loading of the entire page:

```
function setBasicPropertiesAverageScoreChart() {

    //Basic properties
    averageScoreChart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    averageScoreChart.dataProvider = [];
    averageScoreChart.balloon.textAlign = 'left';
    averageScoreChart.startDuration = 1;
    averageScoreChart.numberFormatter = {
      precision:2,decimalSeparator:",",thousandsSeparator:"."
    };
    averageScoreChart.gridAboveGraphs = true;

    //Graph
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.balloonText = "[[balloonText]]";
    graph.valueField = "score";
    graph.fillColorsField = "fillcolor";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0.2;
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;
    averageScoreChart.addGraph(graph);  

    //CategoryAxis
    var catAxis = averageScoreChart.categoryAxis;
    //catAxis.gridCount = averageScoreChart.dataProvider.length;
    catAxis.gridPosition = "start";
    catAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
    catAxis.tickPosition = "start";
    catAxis.tickLength = 20;    

    // ValueAxis
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.minimum = 0;
    //valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.2;
    valueAxis.gridColor = "#FFFFF";
    valueAxis.dashLength = 0;
    //valueAxis.minimum = 0;
    averageScoreChart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    averageScoreChart.write('chartaveragescore');   

}
```

I call this function on the `$(document).ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setBasicPropertiesAverageScoreChart();
    setBasicPropertiesAllScoresChart();       
});
```

The filling of the actual chart is done in another function that is triggerd when a `listbox` or other `html` element is being changed. This function is:

```
function updateAverageScore() {

    showLoader();

    var organization = $("#organization").val();
    var indicator = $("#indicators").val();
    var funcid = "fill_chart_average_score";

    $.getJSON('functions/getfunctions.php', {
        "organization":organization,
        "indicator":indicator,
        "funcid":funcid},

    function(dataChart) {
        if (dataChart == null) {
            bootbox.alert("Er ging iets fout. Probeer het nogmaals");
        } else {
            averageScoreChart.dataProvider = dataChart;
            averageScoreChart.categoryField = "organisatie";
            averageScoreChart.validateData();               
          }
    });

    hideLoader();
}
```

Most important goal of this function is to get `json` data from `MySQL` and set this data as the `dataProvider` for the chart.

When this function is called for the first time I get the bouncy effet of the filling of the chart, but all the changes after the first one, the effect doesn't appear anymore.

I can't seem to figure out why the effect only performs the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: in the function that changes the `dataProvider` I again call the function that sets the basic properties of the `AmChart`.

My function now is:

```
function updateAverageScore() {

    showLoader();

    var organization = $("#organization").val();
    var indicator = $("#indicators").val();
    var funcid = "fill_chart_average_score";

    $.getJSON('functions/getfunctions.php', {
        "organization":organization,
        "indicator":indicator,
        "funcid":funcid},

    function(dataChart) {
        if (dataChart == null) {
            bootbox.alert("Er ging iets fout. Probeer het nogmaals");
        } else {
            setBasicPropertiesAverageScoreChart();
            averageScoreChart.dataProvider = dataChart;
            averageScoreChart.categoryField = "organisatie";
            averageScoreChart.validateData();               
          }
    });

    hideLoader();
}
```

This works :).